# C Program - Custom Text Editor Program

Tags: c

I am building a program for class that is supposed to function as a very basic text-based text editor. It has 9 commands that can be passed to it, each resulting in a different command and we are using a doubly linked list to manage the lines of text that can be appended, inserted, removed and navigated through. I have been given a few functions to work with, and although most of my questions I think are more conceptual, I'll provide these given functions as a basis of background information:

```
// Function: get_line
// Reads a line (of arbitrary length) from an input source (stdin or file)
// and returns a pointer to the array that stores the line read
//
char *get_line(FILE *f)
{
    int size = 80; // initial size of memory block allocated

    char *linePtr = malloc(size);  // allocate memory block

    if (linePtr != NULL) { // if allocation successful
        int c = EOF;

        // read a line of text and replace newline character
        // with a string terminator character
        int i = 0;
        while ((c = getc(f)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            linePtr[i++] = (char) c;
            if (i == size) {
                size *= 2;
                linePtr = realloc(linePtr, size);
            }
        }
        linePtr[i] = '\0';

        // if end-of-file before any characters were read,
        // release the whole buffer
        if (c == EOF && i == 0) {
            free(linePtr);
            linePtr = NULL;
        } else {
            // release unused portion of memory
            linePtr = realloc(linePtr, i+1);
        }
    }

    return linePtr;
}
```

My self-defined "append" function:

```
//
// Function: append_line
// Inserts a line after the current line (or node) in the linked-list
//
void append_line(char *t)
{
    line *new_stack;
    line *tmp;
    new_stack = malloc(sizeof(line));
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(line));

    if((new_stack == NULL) || (tmp == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory to allocate. Closing application.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(current_line == NULL) {
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = new_stack;
            current_line = new_stack;
            new_stack->prev = NULL;
            new_stack->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        tmp = current_line->next;
        current_line->next = new_stack->prev;
        new_stack->next = tmp;
        current_line = new_stack;
    }

    new_stack->text = t;
    free(tmp);
}
```

And this is my read_file function that doesn't really do anything yet, but I'm not exactly sure if I've got the right mind-set going into the creation of this function:

```
// Function: read_file
// Reads text from the specified file and calls append_line to insert lines
// into the linked-list. It returns the number of lines read.
//
int read_file(char *filename)
{
    char * temp, no_command;
    temp = strtok(filename, " ");
    while(temp != NULL) {
        no_command = temp;
        temp = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    /* By doing this --^, I hope it will set temp to the actual
    // file name after tokenization and completely ignore
    // the command that comes with filename */
    FILE *fin;
    int counter = 0;

    fin = fopen(no_command, "r");
    if(fin == NULL) {
        printf("You have entered a file that does not exist.");
        exit(0);
    }
    get_line(fin);
    fclose(fin);
}
```

1. If I wanted to send `get_line` input entered by the user from another function, could I send `get_line` `stdin` for it to recognize user input typed on-screen? Or would I have to make use of some form of `fgets` to send it the information?
2. If the user should be allowed to enter in multiple lines by separating them with the enter key (aka `\n`), and is expected to be allowed to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to continue with the function, how does one tell the application to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the EOF?
3. My `get_line` function takes in an entire file, and outputs a line. I am instructed to make use of multiple calls of `get_line` to take files of multiple lines and send each line into their own respective stack entry. How do I tell the application, "Here's the same file, but I want you to NOW check the next line instead of the one you output previously"? I assume that once I figure this out, I can apply the same logic to input entered in on the fly by the user.

I have been instructed that the `get_line` function is complete, so I feel like in the places I would call `get_line` (such as in `read_file`), I would need to control how much is sent to `get_line` at a time by making `read_file` read up to the point where a `\n` is encountered, change it to an end-of-line symbol (aka `'\0'`) and send it to `get_line`, and then somehow have read_file continue after that point doing the same thing until EOF is reached. But I also feel like a lot of this functionality is within the `get_line` function as well... so I suppose I'm confused on the implementation of my given functions.

I'll probably have more questions in the future, but for now, I believe this initial question is long-winded enough. I'm hoping that figuring these things out, the rest of it will just click in place within my mind. Thank you for your time!

Comment: In your `append_line` function you have a serious memory corruption error: Do _not_ allocate or free memory for the `tmp` pointer. Reason is you allocate memory, then reassign the pointer, and free the other pointer. This will leak the originally allocated memory, and free a node that's in use.

Comment: You will also get a compilation error for your `read_file` function, because `no_command` is not a pointer, and you assign a pointer to it.

Comment: Okay, I see the no_command issue, I wasn't sure if that notation was acceptable or not. In regards to tmp, if I shouldn't allocate memory to it (since my thought process was - store current line's next node, reassign current line's next then to the new stack's previous and then make new stack's next equal to tmp which (I had hoped) would store all the info of current line's next node, and then free the memory of tmp since I wasn't using it). May I ask what I should do to indicate that the user can add a node in the middle of the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of more errors in the `append_line` function, for example you use `new_stack->prev` before it's initialized.

Here comes my take on it:

```
void append_line(char *t)
{
    /* Allocate and clear (i.e. set all to 0) */
    line *new_stack = calloc(1, sizeof(line));

    if(current_line == NULL) {
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = current_line = new_stack;
        }
    }
    else {
        new_stack->next = current_line;
        new_stack->prev = current_line->prev;

        if (current_line->prev)
            current_line->prev->next = new_stack;
        else
            head = new_stack;  /* No previous node, means current_line is at head */

        current_line = new_stack;
    }

    new_stack->text = t;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused as to how linked lists work in general, let alone, doubly linked lists. I understand most of what's going on here but the line you have `if(current_line->prev)`, what is this checking? I was going to ask about the lines above, but I think I understand now - because `current_line` is just a pointer to a node, `current_line` is the position of the next node in the line, and its previous will be the node before `new_stack`, am I right? Thank you so much for all of your clarifications.

Comment: @Newwisdom01 The `if (current_line->prev)` check is to make sure that the `current_line->prev` pointer is not `NULL`.

Comment: Okay, I see now - I'm going to go ahead and mark your response as the answer, but I still have some of the other questions that no one was able to help with. I don't think anyone will be though given the time it's been out without a response. Thank you for your help again; the way you wrote the append_line function has helped me better understand what's going on with this stack.